# Audio not the same after Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, audio, windows-update, speakers

I downloaded a Windows 10 update yesterday, and since, the audio has not been of the same quality. Also, for some reason, the mute button on my keyboard is now always reading that it is muted even when the (weak) volume is playing.

What I have tried:

1. I have updated drivers using both the Windows tool and using Driver Booster. Neither helped.
2. I have tried to set speakers to default device. That didn't work.
3. I have tried to disable all enhancements via going to playback > Speakers > Properties > Enhancements > disable all enhancements. It didn't help.
4. I also tried playing around with some audio quality settings. It did nothing.
5. I have tried using the audio troubleshooter. It could not find a problem.
6. Oddly enough, when I tried playing a Windows audio test, the audio came through pretty well and from both speakers, but YouTube videos and other audio are really bad.

It almost sounds like one speaker is not even playing. I have seen on some help forums that a system restore might resolve the problem. This is an option that I am considering as I only installed the update yesterday. Can anyone please help with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> It almost sounds like one speaker is not even playing.

Is it a desktop? In case positive, have you moved it around? Since one of the speakers is not playing, there's a chance it's related to the speaker itself or the connection to the PC. Usually, if the cable isn't plugged properly that might lead to one of the speakers malfuncioning or a unbalanced sound. Since you have already covered pretty much the main options windows gives you, I'd check that next.

Comment: Nope. It is a laptop. Also, it sounds like one is not working, but I can't really be sure. I just know that the audio is much weaker and sounds much more distant. I now also tried to uninstall the speaker driver and restart, but that didn't help either.

Comment: Try uninstalling the sound drivers and reinstalling them. If that doesn't work, I'd advise you to take it to a technician to see if the problem isn't on the speaker it self. Sometimes it can be a bad sodder.

Comment: Windows reinstalls it if it is uninstalled and the computer is restarted. I don't think that it is a physical problem with the speaker as this problem started from the exact moment that the laptop was restarted after the update. Either that or the speaker going at that time is the most coincidental timing I have ever heard of.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and figured out how to fix it.  Windows 10 software uninstalled a lot of previous drivers and software, like IE Favorites, REALTEK Sound Driver, etc.  Here's what I did to get my sound back to normal (doesn't sound like AM radio and actually has real bass)!

1. You need to download and install REALTEK HD Audio Driver from their Website.  Here is the link. 
   http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false
2. Once you've done this and restarted your computer, you will still have to manually install the driver (at least I did) because it still wouldn't properly install from their website.  If it does, great, you won't need the next steps.  On the Realtek website under where you downloaded the driver, there is a readme file.  Download or print that file where it tells you how to manually install the driver.  Looks like this:

   > Manual driver install by INF :
   >
   > ---
   >
   > 1. Go to "Control Panel”and select "Hardware and Sound".
   > 2. Select "Device Manager" on Devices and Printers
   > 3. Right click on the "High Definition Audio Device" of Device Manager and select "Update
   >      Driver Software" on pop up menu.
   > 4. Select "Browse my computer for driver software" option.
   > 5. Browse Realtek Audio driver location and press "Next" button.
   > 6. Installing Realtek Audio driver.
   > 7. Windows has finished installing the Realtek audio driver.
3. Once you complete the above manual install and restart your computer your sound should be much better.  Also, when you open your sound control window, you should see it has changed a bit and has few more options and controls.